# Table with dynamic looping

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have created table with dynamic looping (if I have 100 of records, it should show only 15 record in one table)

With this I have 20 records creating two tables is done but the problem is in column dynamic is not getting and same records are displaying, for displaying in one table 15 records and 5 records in other table:

[image: my table]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$total = $totalQues / 15;

for ($row = 0; $row < $total; $row++)
    {
    echo '<table aria-describedby="example2_info" id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable custom-table pull-left col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">';
    echo '<tbody aria-relevant="all" aria-live="polite" role="alert">';
    echo '<tr  class="odd black">';
    echo '<td class=" text-center">Q</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">C</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">U</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $j = 0;
    $k = 0;
    $l = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++)
        {
        $j = $i + $totalQues;
        $k = $i + 30;
        $l = $i + 45;
        $m = $i + 1;
        $n = $k + 1;
        $o = $l + 1;
        if (empty($r[1][$i]->corr_ans))
            {
            echo '<tr style = "color:green;">
                  <td>' . $m . '</td>   
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  </tr>';
            }
          else
            {
            $uans = strtolower($r[1][$i]->corr_ans);
            $cans = strtolower($r[1][$i]->user_ans);
            $u = ord($uans);
            $cr = ord($cans);

            // echo "u=".$u."cr=".$cr;

            if ($u == $cr):
                echo '<tr style = "color:green;">
                      <td>' . $m . '</td>   
                      <td>' . strtoupper($r[1][$i]->corr_ans) . '</td>
                      <td>' . strtoupper($r[1][$i]->user_ans) . '</td>
                      </tr>';
            else:
                echo '<tr style = "color:red;">
                      <td>' . $m . '</td>   
                      <td>' . strtoupper($r[1][$i]->corr_ans) . '</td>
                      <td>' . strtoupper($r[1][$i]->user_ans) . '</td>
                      </tr>';
            endif;
            }
        }
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: any one please help me to slove this question

Comment: do you want to have `$total`  number of tables or rows? I really could not understand.

Comment: Since your code is not working it is not a good idea for us to use your code to figure out what it is you are trying to do. Maybe you can explain in understandable English what it is you want to do. Like a function takes argument a and b, a is ... b is ... it will return ... depending on ...

Comment: number of tables.   but inside one for loop creating same records @seethrough you can refer my image i atteched

Comment: @HMR  I have 20 records as totalQues,  i have to create a table which has limit of 15 column and rest 5 column has to display  another table

Comment: @HMR I will get  20 question of correct and user answer  i.e corr_ans = B and user_ans = B , corr_ans = B and user_ans = A . like i have to show that answers in table with dynamic looping, Imagine that if get 100 question (max per table in column is 15) 100/15 = 7 Tables  [100 => Question, 15 column per table &  7 table is result (6 table will have 15 coulmn and 1 table have 10 colum) ]

Comment: So each table has only one row? Or each table has a row of correct answer and a row of answer given by user?

Comment: @HMR Row will be same for every table Q (Question) C (correct) U (User anser)

Comment: You are mixing up row and column. Each table has 3 columns but max 15 rows.

Comment: @HMR Yes sir   but thing is it may get 100 or 200 records for that  limiting the table for 15  rows  column 3 (Q,U,C)  (freeze)

Comment: @GaganTej I left an answer for you. Please chose it as correct if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following code should do the job for you:

```
$numberOfTables = $totalQues/15;
$maxRows = 15

 for($table = 0; $table < $numberOfTables; $table ++){
    echo '<table aria-describedby="example2_info" id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable custom-table pull-left col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">';
             echo '<tbody aria-relevant="all" aria-live="polite" role="alert">';
               echo     '<tr  class="odd black">';
                echo        '<td class=" text-center">Q</td>';
                echo        '<td class="text-center">C</td>';
                 echo       '<td class="text-center">U</td>';
                   echo '</tr>';
                    $tableMax = ($table < $numberOfTables-1 ? $maxRows*($table+1) : $totalQues)
                    for($row = $table*$maxRows; $row < $tableMax; $row++){
                        if (!empty($r[1][$row]->corr_ans)) {
                            $uans = strtolower($r[1][$row]->corr_ans);
                            $cans = strtolower($r[1][$row]->user_ans);
                            $u = ord($uans);
                            $cr = ord($cans);
                             //echo "u=".$u."cr=".$cr;
                            $color = ($u == $cr ? 'green' : 'red');
                                echo '<tr style = "color:'.$color.'">
                                <td>' . $row . '</td>   
                                <td>' . strtoupper($r[1][$row]->corr_ans) . '</td>
                                <td>' . strtoupper($r[1][$row]->user_ans) . '</td>
                                </tr>';

                        }
                    }   
                   echo '</tbody>';
                echo'</table>';
        }

            ?>
```

Comment: @HMR  no sir im getting error on table, one table creating  15 rows but another missing the one full column

Comment: @GaganTej i think you addressed the last comment to a different person, and secondly, I updated my answer, have a try

Comment: @GaganTej sorry for this many corrections, I am not sure what your datastructure is like. Leave a message if it is not working again

Comment: A *`"have a try on this"`* is not adequate to explain your changes.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I have changed this several times already, and this was from very first time i posted the answer

Comment: multiplying the tables  and  twice i am getting values @seethrough

Comment: not limiting to 15 rows and continues  of table creating

Comment: @seethrough  Sir  tables are reverse in order last values are coming first, first are coming at last

Comment: @seethrough   data [[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 278
                    [test_id] => 130
                    [question_id] => 279
                    [corr_ans] => C
                    [user_ans] => a
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 279
                    [test_id] => 130
                    [question_id] => 280
                    [corr_ans] => A
                    [user_ans] => b
                ))

Comment: @seethrough Code is working Sir  Have a grate day :)